# How to Change the Micro sec to Miili sec and adding back to date time object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, cx-oracle

I am trying to collect the data using python file and storing the data in oracle db using the cx_oracle. One column among is ins_timestamp, we are initializing this with ins_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()and storing in the DB.

The datetime.datetime.now() contains the micro sec, we want the milli sec of datetime.datetime.now() to be stored in the DB.

Can someone help me how to change the micro sec to milli sec in datetime object?

Python 3.8
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Datetime has [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat):

```
import datetime as dt
n= dt.datetime.utcnow()
print(n)
print(n.isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds'))
```

Out:

```
2023-01-05 22:55:31.693266
2023-01-05 22:55:31.693
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to get the string. How to get the output value in datetime object to store in the oracle db?

Answer (score 1):

With the schema:

```
drop table t purge;
create table t (c timestamp);
```

Try code like:

```
n = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print(n.isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds'))
cursor.setinputsizes(bv=oracledb.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP)
cursor.execute("insert into t (c) values (:bv)", bv=n)
```

Note I am using python-oracledb, which is the latest version of cx_Oracle, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  However the code will be similar for cx_Oracle.

If you want to truncate the microseconds, a naive approach is to do:

```
n = n.replace(microsecond=(n.microsecond // 1000) * 1000)
```

but you would want to round it - this is left as an exercise for you.